# How does chromosome doubling occur?

Tags: genetics

Sterile hybrid with genome AB undergoes doubling of chromosome set to form fertile tetraploid with genome AABB. 
But since A and B is not homologous, synapsis cannot occur at prophase I, so there is no meiosis. 
So how does the chromosomes double? If through non-disjunction in mitosis, where did it occur? Did it occur in one cell only or all of the cells in the organism? 
Did non-disjunction occurs at gonad to produce AABB cell, then it undergo meiosis to form AB gametes, and then self fertilise with AB gamete to form AABB offspring?

Comment: Kindly elaborate in which step of this entire process you are indicating non-disjunction? it seems simply a DNA replication can cause chromosome doubling or polyploidy. .

Comment: @AlwaysConfused  DNA replication occurs only at meiosis or mitosis right? So in this case, it occurs in mitosis?